# how to open new activity on list view with image and texxt clicked

Tags: android

hello i was doing one application and i have a listview with imageView and textView how do i open a new activity on item click on the list view items here is my code,

```
public class Chapters extends Activity {

// Array of strings for ListView Title
String[] listviewTitle = new String[]{
        "ListView Title 1", "ListView Title 2", "ListView Title 3", "ListView Title 4",
        "ListView Title 5", "ListView Title 6", "ListView Title 7", "ListView Title 8",
};
int[] listviewImage = new int[]{
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
};
String[] listviewShortDescription = new String[]{
        "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description",
        "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description", "Android ListView Short Description",
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chapters);


    final List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("listview_title", listviewTitle[i]);
        hm.put("listview_discription", listviewShortDescription[i]);
        hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(listviewImage[i]));
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title", "listview_discription"};
    int[] to = {R.id.listview_image, R.id.listview_item_title, R.id.listview_item_short_description};

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.chapters_image_text, from, to);
     final ListView androidListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    androidListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    androidListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            //what code do i insert here to open new activity Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use that code in your `onItemClick` Method to show a Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want to open another Activity use this:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MyActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thank you but the previous displays  a toast of message in every item, i would like to open an individual activity on each item like

Comment: using if statement or switch

Comment: @wandle-innocents This is just an example of opening a browser; what sort of activity would you like to open? Nothing's mentioned about that in the OP; but to do it you'll need to list the desired Activity's class, like Lukas mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion,you can use ArrayAdapter class like this:

1- create an arrayAdapter class:

```
    private class YourArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public Context context;
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false);
        //get your views which exist in a one item ex:
        TextView textView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //you can use position paramater to know which item was clicked
                Intent intent= new Intent(YourActivity.this, ActivityYouWantToLaunch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public YourArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId,yourArrayList);
        this.context=context;
    }
}
```

2- show listView's items on activity.after you put all arrayList's items,pass your arrayAdapter like this:

```
    YourArrayAdapter yourArrayAdapter= new YourArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.your_item_layout, android.R.id.text1);
    yourListView.setAdapter(yourArrayAdapter);
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks it finally worked I used a switch statement in the onItemClick listener  Switched long l and I was able to open individual activity of each list item